# custom post type "single" don't show my code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

i am trying to show my code inside a costume post type "single" using :

```
<?php if ( post_type_exists( 'portfolio' ) ) {
   echo 'the Book post type exists'; } ?>
```

it shows the ECHO inside the category 'portfolio'.
but i want to show my code inside the "single" that is under portfolio cat (a costume post type)

i have tryed using this aswell:

```
if ( is_singular()
```

but nothing works

Comment: Does that mean - You want to display the text on single post type page `portfolio` when it is in `portfolio` category ?

Comment: yes. that is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is_singular accept an argument that is the `post_type`. And is_object_in_term is a conditional function which checks if given object *(post)* is within the taxonomy term *(category, tag)*. So the code -

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_the_content' );
function wpse_the_content( $content )
{
    if( is_singular('portfolio') )
    {
        $content .= '<p>the Book post type exists</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Your custom post type `portfolio` should already be registered with taxonomy - `category`. Or if it's a custom taxonomy, replace the second argument on `is_object_in_term` function to that.

Comment: this dosn't work for me. i don't see any change. i put the code in the functions.php. see here: http://zeevm.co.il/dror/?portfolio=test-drive

Comment: My answer is based on your question. However, i found two issue. 1. You provided link post is not assigned with a category named 'portfolio', 2. the code i did provided, should go on the `single.php` or `single-portfolio.php`, not `functions.php`.

Comment: thank you. well i am building a plugin and i wish for that to work automaticly, without changing theme files. 2) what do you mean not category named 'portfolio' ?... please explain

Comment: thank you so much but this still dosn't work for me. i think i mite be puting the wrong phrase under: if( is_singular('portfolio') ).

the costume post type category name is portfolio. see:
function portfolio_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type general name'),